# UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext returns unexpected nil

Tags: iphone, ios, quartz-graphics

I have the following code:

```cpp
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
screenImageContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
ctx = screenImageContext;

UIGraphicsPushContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
ctx  = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

NSLog(@" %@",screenImageContext);
UIImage * result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); // Returns nil

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(result, nil, nil, nil);

UIGraphicsPopContext();
result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); // returns valid result
```

My problem is that `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` returns nil, while the second one after `UIGraphicsPopContext` returns the correct result.

The docs clearly states that `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` will return nil when either the context is nil or the current context isn't a graphic context, but both these problems aren't happening here.

If anyone could shed some light over this i'd be very grateful
Shai.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this issue or not?

Comment: Honestly it was asked by a friend from work (its his code), i'll ask him if it was resolved. Thanks for your assistance regardless!

Comment: I know its old but @Jamie Stewart do you know of a way where in I can retain the screenImageContext in the snippet above and then reuse it later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my understanding of things your issue is stemming from the following line

```
UIGraphicsPushContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
```

With this call you're trying to make the current context the current context. This really doesn't make any sense.

Also with your code it's a little scrambled, you call UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() which will return the current context, then you call UIGraphisBeginImageContext(CGSize size) which as stated in the doc's

> Creates a bitmap-based graphics context and makes it the current context

Then you get the current graphics context again which is now a bitmap-based graphics context thanks to the previous call, then you overwrite the original CGContextRef ("ctx") that you just retrieved.

I'm not 100% certain what you were aiming to achieve with your code but if you were just trying to capture the contents of a bitmap-based context in an image and save it to the photo album then the following code will do that.

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(320, 480); //Screen Size on iPhone device
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);  //Create a new Bitmap-based graphics context (also makes this the current context)
CGContextRef screenImageContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); //get a reference to the context we just made above
NSLog(@" %@",screenImageContext);
//NOTE: without any drawring code in here this will just be a blank image (white/alpha)
// or an image set to whatever the current UIColor is set to
//So you may want to add some drawing code in here. Although TBH I'm not sure what you were originally
// trying to achieve.
UIImage * result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); // Returns nil
NSLog(@" %@",result); //just output this to demonstrate that it's non null/nil
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(result, nil, nil, nil);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); //Removes the current bitmap-based graphics context from the top of the stack
```

Hope that helps.